# no such column: gallery_image.albums_id Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm pretty new to Django and I am trying to learn as much as possible.

I am not sure why I am getting this error:

```
no such column: gallery_image.albums_id
```

traceback:

```
Traceback:
File "/Users/bradfordli/Development/DjangoEnvironment/django_1_6_4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/bradfordli/Development/DjangoEnvironment/django_1_6_4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  432.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/bradfordli/Development/DjangoEnvironment/django_1_6_4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  99.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/bradfordli/Development/DjangoEnvironment/django_1_6_4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/bradfordli/Development/DjangoEnvironment/django_1_6_4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  198.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/bradfordli/Development/DjangoEnvironment/django_1_6_4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  29.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/bradfordli/Development/DjangoEnvironment/django_1_6_4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  99.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/bradfordli/Development/DjangoEnvironment/django_1_6_4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  25.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/Users/bradfordli/Development/DjangoEnvironment/django_1_6_4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changelist_view
  1411.             'selection_note': _('0 of %(cnt)s selected') % {'cnt': len(cl.result_list)},
File "/Users/bradfordli/Development/DjangoEnvironment/django_1_6_4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __len__
  77.         self._fetch_all()
File "/Users/bradfordli/Development/DjangoEnvironment/django_1_6_4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  854.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "/Users/bradfordli/Development/DjangoEnvironment/django_1_6_4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in iterator
  220.         for row in compiler.results_iter():
File "/Users/bradfordli/Development/DjangoEnvironment/django_1_6_4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in results_iter
  713.         for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
File "/Users/bradfordli/Development/DjangoEnvironment/django_1_6_4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  786.         cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Users/bradfordli/Development/DjangoEnvironment/django_1_6_4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  69.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "/Users/bradfordli/Development/DjangoEnvironment/django_1_6_4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  53.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Users/bradfordli/Development/DjangoEnvironment/django_1_6_4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  99.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "/Users/bradfordli/Development/DjangoEnvironment/django_1_6_4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  53.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Users/bradfordli/Development/DjangoEnvironment/django_1_6_4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  451.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /admin/gallery/image/
Exception Value: no such column: gallery_image.albums_id
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
import os
from PersonalWebsite.settings import MEDIA_ROOT

class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 60)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_image_by_album(self):
        images = []
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, 'albums', self.title)):
            mypath = os.sep.join(os.path.join(root, file).split(os.sep[4:]))
            images.append(mypath)
        return images


class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.tag

class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 60, blank = True, null = True)
    #image = models.FileField(upload_to = get_upload_file_name)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank = True)
    albums = models.ForeignKey(Album)
    width = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True)
    height = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.image.name 

class AlbumAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ["title"]
    list_display = ["title"]

class TagAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["tag"]

class ImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ["title"]
    list_display = ["__unicode__", "title", "created"]
    list_filter = ["tags", "albums"]

admin.site.register(Album, AlbumAdmin)
admin.site.register(Tag, TagAdmin)
admin.site.register(Image, ImageAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ran syncdb yet? If so, I suggest you delete your database(if you don't mind losing your data) and create it again to fix possible inconsistencies.